# In Clojure how is a macro different from a function?

Tags: clojure

I just started with macros and made a simple one to return maximum number out of a list.

```
(defmacro macro-max [list] (apply max list))
```

and If I make a function to do the same, it will be.

```
(defn  macro-max [list] (apply max list))
```

I am just exploring Clojure, so I don't know much.

I may sound completely silly to experts, But it looks like I can pretty much define a function instead of a macro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference comes to life when you don't want to evaluate your arguments unless needed.

Consider this example:

```
(defn unless [pred body]
  (when (not pred)
    body))
```

This doesn't work since arguments to a function are eagerly evaluated. So body always runs, as shown below:

```
(unless (zero? 2)
        (prn "Not zero!"))
;; "Not zero!"

(unless (zero? 0)
        (prn "Not zero!"))
;; "Not zero!"
```

Both executions above print "Not zero!", which is clearly wrong.

The only way to write our `unless` utility is by using a macro:

```
(defmacro unless [pred body]
  `(when (not ~pred)
     ~@body))
```

Now if we give it a try, we'll see it works as expected:

```
(unless (zero? 2)
        (prn "Not zero!"))
;; "Not zero!"

(unless (zero? 0)
        (prn "Not zero!"))
;; this prints nothing
```

Macros only evaluate its arguments when the developer decides to.

You'll notice some special characters in the macro such as `, ~ and ~@. They stand for syntax-quote, unquote and unquote-splicing, respectively and are explained [here](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters).

I suggest you study these symbols.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The syntax quote and unquote features are sometimes useful outside of macros as well.

Answer (score 1):

If a function can do, then by all means use a function. Clojure libraries follow this rule, so probably most macros defined there cannot really be expressed as functions. Take the `->>` macro:

```
(->> 
   "abcdefghij"
   (take 5)
   (drop 3)
   (apply str))
```

The above evaluates to "de". A function could not do that, since the arguments of the macro do not make sense when evaluated by themselves - `(take 5)` raises an error when evaluated.

What the macro does is modify the forms *before* they are evaluated (by inserting the previous expression as the last argument of the form.) This is what only a macro can do, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are functions. The difference is only in evaluation time (macros are evaluated at macro expansion time, which is a step in compiling, functions are evaluated at runtime). Also, Macros work on S-Expressions (so macro is a bit like a function where you quote every single argument, i.e. you could easily replace any macro `(mac a b)` with a function `(fun 'a 'b)`.

Comment: "you could easily replace any macro `(mac a b)` with a function `(fun 'a 'b)`". Definitely  not easily. For this to work either a) the function would need to resolve the symbols in the context of the caller or b) the caller would have to `eval` the result of the function within own context. The b) would be closer to how macros work in reality.

Comment: @RafałDowgird I'm talking about what the macro does. The macro just works on S-expressions, and that's exactly what you can do with a 'normal' function too. That the result of a macro is inserted in place of the macro invocation is IMHO not _that_ important when it comes to "Functions vs. Macros".

Answer (score -7):

I don't have experience with macros but it will allow you extend combilier by your functions. I am not sure but it is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Why did you bother answeing if you `don't have experience` and are `not sure`?

Comment: Seriously. which part of your answer answers this question even by 1% ?